# How can I get convert wstringstream to char*?

Tags: qt, c++11, stringstream, wstring

how convert wstringstream to char* ?? (Language c++)

I need this conversion to use the function writeRawData of the qdatastream.h library.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Do you know about *casting*?

Comment: yes, I know about casting!

Comment: Then get the string. Get a pointer to the first character in the string. And cast that.

Comment: I'm curious as to why this was upvoted when it does not show any evidence that the user had researched or tried anything before asking us how to do it.

Comment: Ok, but if I have a Special characters (ò, é, ...) I lost its and I don' t want this happen... Do you have other solution? Thanks...

Comment: [edit] your post to include any information on things like that, i.e. what you tried, and what problem you encountered. People shouldn't have to play an easter egg hunt to figure out what your question really is.

Comment: I have researched and tried anything before asking you how to do it. I tried all day..

Comment: My point was that your question should include **what** "anything" you've tried, so people don't tell you things you've already trjed and discredited, or so they can tell you what fixes to make to what you tried. Just posting _'help me do X'_ is not useful and is likely to waste your and other people's time.

Comment: Ok, I have understand your suggestion. But for me is not so easy explain this problems on paper. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `wstringstream::str()` to retrieve the content of the stream.
And then depending on your need you can either convert it to a `QString` so that the QDataStream can handle the string for you or just write the bytes of the wstring:

```
void f(wstringstream &stream, QDataStream &qstream)
{
    wstring content = stream.str();
    QString str = QString::fromStdWString(content);
    qstream << str;
}

void g(wstringstream &stream, QDataStream &qstream)
{
    wstring content = stream.str();
    qstream.writeRawData(static_cast<const char *>(content.c_str()), content.length() * sizeof(wchar_t));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wstringstream is a basic_stringstream, you could extract line, char, text from it 
look at that http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/wstringstream/

and you could retreive one example from that http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/basic_stringstream/str/

Comment: Ok, but if I have a Special characters (ò, é, ...) I lost its and I don' t want this happen... Do you have other solution? Thanks...